# Java plugin does not attach to debug session in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, plugins

this functionality used to work and now it seems broken, I a do not know how to diagnose it.
I am developing a java Applet that runs in a browser.  I used to set up the runtime parameters in the java console to (Windows platform):

-Djava.compiler=NONE -Xnoagent -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=n,suspend=n

This setting appears both in the User and System tabs in the Java console.

Then I would start a debug session in eclipse for my applet project and set it to listen on port 8000.  When I launch the browser and the applet is loaded, it would attach to eclipse and I was able to debug and set breakpoints, etc.

Now, it seems that this is no longer happening. When I launch the debug session in Eclipse, I do see port in LISTENING mode and owned by javaw.exe, which is correct.  The only problem is that when the browser loads the Java plugin, it does not honor the "Runtime Parameters" and does not connect to the listening debug session in eclipse.

I have the latest Java update installed.

What else should I be looking into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just resolved my issue.
I edited:
C:\users\\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties
and added the pararameters as follows:

deployment.javaws.jre.0.args=-Djava.compiler\=NONE -Xnoagent -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp\:transport\=dt_socket,address\=8000,server\=n,suspend\=n

When i added the runtime parameters through the UI, they went to 
"deployment.javaws.jre.1.args" so I duplicated them into "deployment.javaws.jre.0.args"

Comment: You should accept your own answer, so that this question doesn't come up as unanswered.

Comment: But when I do I get a popup saying you can accept your answer in xx hours.