# java update to 1.8.0_73 now debug doesn't work

Tags: java, debugging, applet

I've run a 1.8.0_73 java update, and since then I cannot debug applets.  I have the following in my java control panel runtime parameters:

-Djava.compiler=NONE -Xnoagent -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8292,server=y,suspend=n

When I start up my applet, I used to be able to see a listener on port 8292, but now there is nothing.

No errors show up in my java console.

Thoughts?

Comment: Applets in 2016? Why? Don't you have the opportunity to migrate to jnlp instead?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I don't sign the checks :)  I did find another post which solved my question:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570738/java-plugin-does-not-attach-to-debug-session-in-eclipse)